# Speakers only pop & hiss after system crash - no more sound

Tags: 11.04, sound

My system has been suffering from random freezes lately. I think it *might* have something to do with my graphics card which I've hopefully fixed it.

However, after one of those freezes I was forced to reboot my system and since then my sound no longer works and more specifically all I hear out of my speakers are random pops every 5-10 seconds.

This was a clean install of Ubuntu 11.04 and sound was working previously just fine. The speakers still work as I've tested them on another machine.

I was not attempting to fix the graphics card problem at the time the sound stopped working, I fixed that problem later after the sound was already popping.

I've tried removing ~/.pulse & ./pulse-cookie

I've tried reinstalling pulseaudio with:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

I've added `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to my /etc/modprobe.d` file.

My sound is not muted.

The speakers pop even if my volume *is* muted.

`alsamixer` shows that all my volume levels are set to 100%

I do not have my HDMI selected instead of my regular stereo analog output (in fact, I've disabled my HDMI output entirely in System -> Preferences -> Sound)

I've made sure that my user account is added to the audio, pulse and pulse access groups.

Here are a couple of outputs that might be useful:

$ dmesg | grep -i hda

```
[    5.455970] HDA Intel 0000:00:14.2: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16

[    5.545302] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    5.545305] hda_intel: Disable MSI for Nvidia chipset
[    5.545349] HDA Intel 0000:01:00.1: setting latency timer to 64
[  471.612677] hda-intel: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
[ 1078.442662] hda-intel: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #2. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
```

$ cat /proc/asound/cards

```
0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                  HDA ATI SB at 0xfbff8000 irq 16
1 [U0x46d0x825    ]: USB-Audio - USB Device 0x46d:0x825
                  USB Device 0x46d:0x825 at usb-0000:00:13.2-3, high speed
2 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                  HDA NVidia at 0xfe77c000 irq 19
```

$ aplay -l | grep card

```
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
```

$ sudo lsmod | grep snd

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     28103  4 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   336693  1 
snd_hda_intel          33211  2 
snd_hda_codec         103804  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_usb_audio         112426  1 
snd_usbmidi_lib        25139  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              13604  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                96625  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30486  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61621  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29602  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14462  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    67382  18   snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hw    dep,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12680  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

This is a desktop machine, not a laptop.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there is any other information that might be helpful.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.